# How does precipitate affect cell potential?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

> A cell is set up with copper and lead electrodes in contact with $\ce{CuSO4(aq)}$ and $\ce{Pb(NO3)2(aq)},$ respectively, at $\pu{25 °C}.$ The standard reduction potentials are:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{Pb^2+ + 2 e- &-> Pb} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{-0.13 V} \\
> \ce{Cu^2+ + 2 e- &-> Cu} &\quad E^\circ &= \pu{+0.34 V}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> If sulfuric acid is added to the $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$ solution, forming a precipitate of $\ce{PbSO4},$ what will happen to the cell potential?

I know the lead is the anode while the copper is the cathode:

$$\ce{Pb(s) + Cu^2+ -> Pb^2+ + Cu(s)}$$

The addition of $\ce{H2SO4}$ will cause less $\ce{Pb^2+}$ to be in the solution, thus causing the equilibrium to push to the right creating more $\ce{Pb^2+}.$ With more $\ce{Pb^2+},$ if you were to put it in the Nernst equation, would the greater number in the log expression cause the cell potential to decrease?

Comment: [Pb^2+] is determined by [SO4^2-] and PbSO4 solubility product.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

The solubility product of $\ce{PbSO4}$ is about $10^{-8}$. Now suppose $[\ce{Pb^{2+}}$] falls down from $\pu{1 M}$ to an arbitrary low value like $\pu{10^{-8} M},$ due to addition of $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions. In this case, Nernst's law can be applied, and the potential of the lead electrode falls from $E^\circ_\ce{Pb} = \pu{-0.13 V}$ down to

$$E_\ce{Pb} = \pu{-0.13 V} + \pu{0.0296 V}\times\log{10^{-8}} = \pu{-0.37 V}\tag{1}$$

As a consequence, the $\ce{Pb}$ potential decreases. But the cell potential increases and goes from the initial value (without sulfate)

$$E^\circ_\mathrm{cell, i} = \pu{0.34 V} - (\pu{-0.13 V}) = \pu{0.47 V}\tag{2}$$

to the final value (after precipitation of lead sulfate)

$$E_\mathrm{cell, f} = \pu{0.34 V} - (\pu{-0.37 V}) = \pu{0.71 V}\tag{3}$$